# Clean code - how to design this class?

Tags: java, oop, coding-style

I have been reading the "Clean code" book and particularly the part on Hybrid classes and the difference between data structures and objects.

I have an SFTPUtil class with one method for deleting a file from an sftp server.

Currently it looks like what is described as a Hybrid class like so:

```
String host;
int port;
String rootDirectory;
String username;
String password;

public void deleteFile(String filename){
 // Code using the instance variables above
}


//GETTERS AND SETTERS FOR INSTANCE VARIABLES
```

But based on this book, it would seem better to just have:

```
public void deleteFile(String filename, String host, int port, String rootDirectory, String username, String password){
 // Code using the instance variables above
}
```

And no instance variables.

Is this a correct assumption? What are peoples thoughts on this and are there better ways again to design this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach depends on the need to reuse your instance variables or your objects. If you need to set your instance variables to use them only once, you are better off without instance variables. However, if you plan on reusing the the values of your instance variables, you are better off with a class to hold their values.

There is a third approach, which strikes a balance between reusing instances and not passing too many parameters. You can define a class to hold `SFTPLoginCredentials`, put instance variables in it, and then provide `static` methods in the utilities class that use variables from the credentials object:

```
public class SFTPLoginCredentials {
    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private final String rootDirectory;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    // Add a constructor and getters for all these instance variables
}
public static class SFTPUtils {
    public static void deleteFile(String filename, SFTPLoginCredentials credentials);
    public static void uploadFile(InputStream data, String filename, SFTPLoginCredentials credentials);
    public static void downloadFile(String filename, OutputStream data, SFTPLoginCredentials credentials);
}
```

Now you can create a single `SFTPLoginCredentials` object, and keep using it in your `SFTPUtils` class, which can become stateless (a major driving factor behind the desire to not introduce unnecessary instance variables).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of holding the SFTP details in a separate class. I think that's a nice way of keeping data structure away from the object. But as pointed out in another answer, where would you see the connection to the sftp server etc being done? Within the static methods?

Comment: @jonlee Yes, in this situation the connection is done within static methods. This lets you keep the method entirely stateless. Unless there is a prohibitive cost to opening a connection for each operation, it's a good idea to do it this way (it may become prohibitive if you need to do something for multiple files in a loop). In situations like that, however, you would be better off introducing another static method that takes a "to do" list of files that need to be deleted, uploaded, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: it's mainly a matter of personal preference. If you feel like you can work easier with one way than the other, then you've got your answer.

That being said you will want to take a look at how you intend to use this class.
I see two main possibilities on how you will use this:

- Remove many files from a server
- Remove a file from many servers

If you have the first use case then it will make a lot of sense to use instance variables for the connection and a method that just takes a filename. This won't force you to keep specifying the connection information and might feel cleaner.

If you have the second use case then it will not make much sense to store them in fields because you will barely use it.

All this combined I'd probably lean towards the first approach myself. A method should have one responsibility and both making the connection AND deleting a file doesn't feel right and by taking the first approach you will also be 'safe' from the code smell that would appear should you have chosen the second approach and it turns out you want to delete many files from the servers in the future (as described in the first approach).

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. one last point would it then be better to have a separate class that represents an SFTPserver and have that as an instance variable rather than the individual fields?

Comment: @jonlee: Dasblinkenlight already does into this specific option but yes, it might. If you only use it to transmit the data once then it won't make a big difference (you construct it and the next call you already retrieve all the values from it, netto you won't have gained much). Usually this is done to easier group a few fields to transfer throughout several method calls. You still have the readability going for it though and it makes it easier to specify new data that relates to the SFTP connection info

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that is not likely to change keep it as simple as possible (the book approach looks fine in that regard), but it really depends what is the requirement and how do you anticipate the code to change in the future.

Lets say you want to add more sftp commands, add caching of connections or have the option to change the implementation in the future this all effects how you design a class. but I think the key point here is don't over design.