# where to put the behaviour of DTOs ? Object vs Data structure clean code

Tags: java, object, dto, behavior

Similar question was posted here [Clean code - how to design this class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064164/clean-code-how-to-design-this-class)

I still don't find an answer though, I'm confused!

I read the book "clean code" too.He is saying in some part you shouldn't mix data structure/Object, whether data structure with no behaviour or an object with behaviour.

In my application we have Data tranfer objects which carry data from external services .These DTO have just data accessors and mutators. So I was considering them as Data structure type.

However **Robert Martin** is saying in his book that `client.isMarried()`  is better than `isMarried(client)` I found this logical as `isMarried` function use attributes only from client class.. it is cleaner.

In many areas in my application we need some behaviour on a certain DTOs I'm confused where to put this behaviour. 
We have made Utils classes that has business logic like

```
ClientUtils { 

   boolean isMarried(Client client) { ...} 
   String getCompleteName(Client client) { ...} 

}
```

Should this go to the service layer ? even if these methods does not manipulate any thing else other than the input object It does not interact with another layer (DAL, services .. )

Comment: Why can't these operations just be on the `client` class?  Perhaps that class is evolving into more of a model than a simple DTO?  Even if it isn't, it's not terrible to put *some* logic on a DTO, if that logic reasonably *belongs* on that DTO.  If that class is the only thing on which that logic operates, and it's the only place in the system which needs it, then it belongs on that class.

Comment: My class Client class is also in an external library so the only way to do that is to extend it because I cannot edit it

Comment: I suspect this should be asked on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you were using Kotlin, this would be a great example use case for extension methods.

Comment: Is this question conflating dtos and persistent entities?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change the Client class due to the external library constraint, I wouldn't extend it.  I suggest making a ClientInfo wrapper class that "has a" Client member instead.

```
class ClientInfo {
    private Client myClient;

    public ClientInfo(Client c) {
        myClient = c;
    }

    public boolean isMarried() { ...} 
    public String getCompleteName() { ...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me, then `Utils` class just means you have a random static method lingering somewhere which contains actual business logic. Why not keep DTOs as DTOs, and create a ClientManager class that has `isMarried` method?

The `ClientInfo` approach that wraps the external object is another option, possibly driven by Domain Driven Security.